# Using the bitlocker cdmlet "Add-BitLockerKeyProtector" via c# to add a passphrase

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to use a cmdlet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649835(v=wps.630).aspx) e.g. Add-BitLockerKeyProtector under Win10 in c#:

```
   PowerShell psNew = PowerShell.Create();
    psNew.AddCommand("Add-BitLockerKeyProtector");
    psNew.AddParameter("MountPoint");
    psNew.AddArgument("d:");
    psNew.AddParameter("Password");
    psNew.AddArgument(SecureString);
    psNew.AddParameter("PasswordProtector");
    var result = psNew.Invoke();
```

SecureString has the type System.Security.String

I always get the same error, regardless of what im changing:

> {"Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert value \"True\" to type \"System.Security.SecureString\". Error: \"Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Security.SecureString'.\""}

Doing this in powershell, everything runs perfectly:

```
`Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint d: -Password $ss -PasswordProtector`
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i properly use this cmdlet under c#?

Comment: `AddArgument` adds positional argument, not value for parameter.